# Looping issues in panda python

Tags: python, pandas

```
def region(reg,new_reg):
    for i in reg.country:
        for j in new_reg.Country:
            for k in new_reg.Continent:
                if i==j:
                   reg.Continent=k
```

How can i improve this, this taking so much time, this is in python pandas. reg and new_reg are  dataframes, both contains strings. If there is a match in a reg.country and new_ reg.country, I want to update reg.continent with the matched data value from new_reg.continent if the reg.country and new_reg.country matches bearing in mind reg.continent is a new dataframe with no value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

reg=pd.DataFrame({'country':['b','c','d','e'],'Continent':['B','C','D','E']})

new_reg=pd.DataFrame({'country':['d','e','f','g'],'Continent':['DD','EE','FF','GG']})

#If country is unique
dfr = reg.set_index('country')
dfnr = new_reg.set_index('country')
dfr['Continent'].update(dfnr['Continent'])

Out[70]: 
        Continent
country          
b               B
c               C
d              DD
e              EE
```

Comment: Assuming reg doesn't have the column of continent and it wants to update its continent from new_reg continent with matching countries.